# How do I set two variable equal to what someone types in java?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Please enter the code: ")
theCode = kb.nextDoulbe();
customerCode = theCode.next().charAt(0);
```

I need theCode to be what they type which will be industrial, commercial or residential and I need customerCode to be the first character (i c or r)

Comment: Use the Scanner class - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.  The code that you posted doesn't provide enough context to help us to help you - what is kb?

Comment: can you provide more info and explain further?

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to read anything as input and assign to variable, you can follow below code:


    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class ScannerDemo1 
    { 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            // Declare the object and initialize with 
            // predefined standard input object 
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

            // String input 
            String name = sc.nextLine(); 

            // Character input 
            char gender = sc.next().charAt(0); 

            // Numerical data input 
            // byte, short and float can be read 
            // using similar-named functions. 
            int age = sc.nextInt(); 
            long mobileNo = sc.nextLong(); 
            double cgpa = sc.nextDouble(); 

            // Print the values to check if the input was correctly obtained. 
            System.out.println("Name: "+name); 
            System.out.println("Gender: "+gender); 
            System.out.println("Age: "+age); 
            System.out.println("Mobile Number: "+mobileNo); 
            System.out.println("CGPA: "+cgpa); 
        } 
    }
```